# Is it possible to control the user interface of an iOS app through a CMS API?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In React Native, if I control a component and change its UI through a CMS API, will the app store allow us to launch our app? Are there any blockers in the app store for this feature? If not, why won't it allow, and are there any alternative approaches?

Could you please confirm if the app store permits such functionality? If not, what are the reasons for disallowing it, and are there any alternative methods available?

Comment: You can definitely render the UI based on response from CMS API, all you have to do is design your app in that way that first it loads the settings from CMS API then apply it on your components.